# Checking img-tag inside div-container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this snippet in my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="images/screen1.jpg">
</div>
```

Is it possible to check the name of the image inside the container?

Comment: what do mean by name? did you mena `screen1.jpg`?

Comment: Do you mean the filename? What have you tried so far.

Comment: then `var name = $('#container img').attr('src').match(/[^/]+$/)[0]`

Comment: BTW, `<img` should close with `/>`

Comment: @Reger, no, in html5.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the image src by this code:

var file = $("#container img").attr("src");

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`$('#container').find('img').attr('src').split('/').pop()`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/j39Rf/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is :

HTML :

```
 <div id="container">
 <img src="images/screen1.jpg">
 </div>
```

JS :

```
var src =$('#container img').attr('src')
alert(src.split('images/').join(""))
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/bqt7A/)